# How to provide AppSpec and Task Definition to CodeDeploy in ECR sourced pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops, amazon-ecs, aws-code-deploy, blue-green-deployment

I want to trigger a blue/green ECS deploy on ECR image update. The deployment stage requires three input artifacts: `imageDetail.json`, `appspec.json` and `taskdef.json`.

While creating a pipeline I pick ECR repository as a source, which creates an `imageDetail.json` SourceArtifact, this is clear. Later in a build stage I can put it in output artifacts.

What I miss completely is how to provide the two remaining files? Should I inline them in the build stage definition `buildspec.yaml` (they are quite big and inlining seems tedious) or fetch them somehow from CodeCommit (so far I thought I can do it without having to set up CodeCommit only for that purpose)?

What is the usual practice for providing those files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you will need to source the other files from a Code repository (github/CodeCommit). This tutorial is a nice guide on the ECS/CodeDeploy deployment pipeline:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/tutorials-ecs-ecr-codedeploy.html

Comment: Storing the files directly in source suggests they can't be managed dynamically; surely AWS provides a means to retrieve generated build artifacts as inputs for ECS? Storing them in source seems like a workaround. E.g. the Image URI is subject to change if using semantic versioning in your image tags, are you going to update a file(s) in source every time your version changes? (which you can really do, because that will trigger another build in the pipeline). Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: The idea is that "imageDetail.json" will be generated dynamically as part of the build process i.e. creating the image, tagging/pushing it and then using the same tag in creating the 'imageDetail.json' artifact. The rest of the 2 files mentioned in the question (appspec/taskdef) will remain static, change infrequently and will be checked into the source code.

Comment: Ok.. But as an example, the taskdef.json needs to reference the image URI, if the tag increments following an update, surely that reference can't be static. I believe it's possible to use a placeholder e.g. "image": "<IMAGE_NAME>" ? .. which can then be overridden by the ImageURI value from imageDetail.json. Is that your understanding also?

Comment: Yes that is correct. The placeholder method in taskdef is used in this tutorial as well: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/tutorials-ecs-ecr-codedeploy.html